# Insert code inside function?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to add code to a function when running.
Is it possible ? This could be the pseudocode:

```
function Insert_code(the_function) 
{
the_function=the_function+ My_code 
run the function using settimeout 
}
```

Of course I'd have to write a code to detect the last parenthesis etc..
Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: what kind of code do you want to be added?

Comment: @tonnot First of all - why would you want to do that? If you want to alter the behaviour of a function - why don't you just write another one?

Comment: What is `the_function`? Is it an actual function object or just the name as a string? Would you be able to change it into a string or do you need it to be a function object?

Comment: Thanks.  I have write a little execution motor, to let ui-refresh. I feed the motor with the functions I want to execute. I have to add on every functio added a MOTOR("next")   callback. I can do it manually but I'm thinking in having something sutitable to any function. By now (manually MOTOR "next") it works.

Answer (score 3):

First of all: This sounds like possibly bad design. Think twice about having to write this the way you do!

First possibility; your parameter is an actual string with code inside (e.g. `insert_code('callme();');`):

```
function insert_code(the_function) {
    setTimeout(the_function + ';someadditionalcode();', 500);
}
```

Second possibility; your parameter is an actual function (e.g. `insert_code(callme);`):

```
function insert_code(the_function) {
    setTimeout(function() {
            someadditionalcode();
            the_function();
        }, 500);
}
```